# How do you start a Rebol3 GUI script without the console showing?

Tags: rebol, rebol3, r3-gui

Currently I start a GUI from the console which involves first loading the GUI with `load-gui` and then run the script which shows the GUI.

How can I start the GUI without a console showing?

Comment: I assume the question is about Rebol 3 on Windows?

Comment: And Linux as well as other platforms where r3gui is supported

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the open/exe action for the R3 script : the R3 exe.