# How to specify in Rebol3 the open/exe action for the R3 script : the R3 exe

Tags: rebol, rebol3, r3-gui

related to this question:
[How do you start a Rebol3 GUI script without the console showing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717336/how-do-you-start-a-rebol3-gui-script-without-the-console-showing)
As I can't quote there because of my low reputation, I opened a new more specific question.

How can that be done exactly, or where can I find more details about how to do it?
I searched now quite some time, but didn't find detailed info.
As I'm new to REBOL3, it's kind of hard to get through the different versions. I use the SAPHIRON build.
Code is just a simple first test:

```
REBOL [title: "first test"]
do %r3-gui.r3

load-gui
view [text "Hello Andreas!"]
```

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows for example, you can associate to rebol scripts, a default program to run.
If your file script name ends with .r3, and if you want to run r3-view.exe when you double clic a .r3 script:
- for windows: right clic the .r3 script, and then clic"open with", then check "default program" and choose "r3-view.exe", then clic OK.